# how to print already interpreted html data in python

Tags: python

I have a HTML file with the following data structure:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="img.jpg"></td>
    <td><a href="file.zip">file.zip</a></td>
    <td align="right">24-Apr-2013 12:42 </td>
    <td align="right">200K</td>
</tr>
...
```

It's basically a simple table and when viewed in Firefox it looks like this:

```
file.zip   22-Apr-2013 12:42   200K
```

I want to extract this three values (file name, date, size) and I could do it e.g. with `split()` but I am wondering if it is possible to print "the html interpreted form" of this in python?

```
import xyz
print xyz.htmlinterpreted(htmlfile.html)
>>> file.zip   22-Apr-2013 12:42   200K
```

That way I could easiely split the data with `split(" ")`. Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HTML parser. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes this a breaze:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
print list(soup.stripped_strings)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                   >>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<tr><td valign="top"><img src="img.jpg"></td><td><a href="file.zip">file.zip</a></td><td align="right">24-Apr-2013 12:42 </td><td align="right">200K</td></tr>''')
>>> print list(soup.stripped_strings)
[u'file.zip', u'24-Apr-2013 12:42', u'200K']
```